# InnerHTML returning Input/Textbox instead of value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value of input/textbox in a table. The rest of code works, but I can't seem to get the value from the input that is in the table cell.

I have tried used `value`, but I get undefined.

This is what I get when I use innerHTML: 
`<input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_0" onblur="getTotal()">`

I expect to get the value of each NumberOfCourses input textbox.

```js
function getTotal() {
  var amt;
  var subTotal = 0;
  var FTA = document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA");

  for (i = 1; i < FTA.rows.length; i++) {

    amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].value;
    alert(amt);
    if (isNaN(amt)) {
      subTotal += 0;
    } else {
      subTotal += parseFloat(amt);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Faculty Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Number Of Courses</th>
    <th scope="col">Courses (Add Comma-separated Courses)</th>
    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_0">Josh</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_0" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="200" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_0" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="something                                                                                                                                                                                               "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_0" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_1">Mary</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="2" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_1" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="300, 500" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_1" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="test                                                                                                                                                                                                    "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_1" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Because the content of the cell is an input. Why don't you try to grab the input's value from within the cell?

Comment: @ZorgoZ, I'm not sure how to do that, can you explain?

Comment: This is your third question about adding the values in the cells. Perhaps ask one question with complete specifications and then wait for the answer that gives you a complete solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to access the value of the `<input>` by reading the `value` of the `<td>`. This is not correct. You need to get the `<input>` element from the `<td>` and get the value of that.

You can use `querySelector` to find the `<input>` and pull the `value` from there.

```js
amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector('input').value
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It describes the problem and offers a solution.

Comment: 1. He needs ALL the inputs in column 1 or named in a specific way 2. `FTA.querySelector('input')`  will be more readable

Comment: @mplungjan No, the problem with his code was the way he was trying to access the value of the textbox. Your answer rewrites all his code and doesn't do anything to explain what the issue was.

Comment: I did not vote, I commented.

Comment: We already determined the problem in comment one under his question

Comment: I get the idea with @mplungjan code, just didn't work for some reason

Comment: The above solution worked, however

Comment: @Juan but do you know why it worked? as in did it answer your question?

Comment: @Adam H Is it because the `querySelector` is selecting the input as an object?

Comment: @Juan - This code works because the `querySelector` is finding the input inside of the cell and getting the value from there.

Comment: PS: You post a snippet. That snippet does not run.

Comment: Thanks @Adam H, and everyone, I've been trying to find a solution to this for quite sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. you need to address the field by name - since your backend adds all sorts of stuff, we can use the $= selector for "ends with"
2. you need to use a selector that takes the fields and not the cells

You COULD have used

```
amt = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector("input").value;
```

but this is more elegant

```js
function getTotal() {
  var amt;
  var subTotal = 0;

  document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA")         // the table
    .querySelectorAll("[name$=iTxtNumberOfCourses]") // the inputs as array using $= name ending on 
    .forEach(el => subTotal += +el.value);           // sum 
    alert(subTotal);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Faculty Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Number Of Courses</th>
    <th scope="col">Courses (Add Comma-separated Courses)</th>
    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_0">Josh</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_0" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="200" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_0" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="something                                                                                                                                                                                               "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_0" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_1">Mary</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="2" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_1" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="300, 500" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_1" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="test                                                                                                                                                                                                    "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_1" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To get an array of values use

```
  // array of values
  var FTA = [...document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA") // the table
    .querySelectorAll("[name$=iTxtNumberOfCourses]")]      // the inputs as array using $= name ending on 
    .map(el => +el.value);                                 // map
    console.log(FTA); // this array can be further reduced to a total
```

Comment: Do I need the `...` before `document` ?

Comment: Yes, or `Array.from()`

Comment: Didn't get the alert on using it

Comment: I am not alerting, I use console.log. Blur the first field and you get all fields from second column

Comment: So what was the problem with his code? How does this address it?

Comment: @AdamH The code is commented. I have added more information.

Comment: @mplungjan Done

Answer (score 0):

Beware: your cell contains an html element, that is the input within. Thus you can't simply access the value, you need to grab the input and then get the value.

```js
function getTotal() {
  var amt;
  var subTotal = 0;
  var FTA = document.getElementById("cphMain_gridFTA");

  for (i = 1; i < FTA.rows.length; i++) {
    var input = FTA.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
    amt = input.value;
    
    if (isNaN(amt)) {
      subTotal += 0;
    } else {
      subTotal += parseFloat(amt);
    }
  }
  
  return subTotal;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Faculty Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Number Of Courses</th>
    <th scope="col">Courses (Add Comma-separated Courses)</th>
    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_0">Josh</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="1" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_0" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="200" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_0" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="something                                                                                                                                                                                               "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_0" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl02$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="cphMain_gridFTA_txtFacultyName_1">Mary</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNumberOfCourses" type="text" value="2" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNumberOfCourses_1" onblur="getTotal()" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtCourses" type="text" value="300, 500" id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtCourses_1" />

    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$iTxtNotes" type="text" value="test                                                                                                                                                                                                    "
        id="cphMain_gridFTA_iTxtNotes_1" style="width:400px;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:220px;">
      <a id="cphMain_gridFTA_ButtonEdit_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMain$gridFTA$ctl03$ButtonEdit&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="alert(getTotal())">Total</button>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution too.